# What is the best way to run multiple threads that must loop 25 times per second without over loading the CPU

Tags: opencv, c++11, visual-c++

Hi I am trying to capture multiple frames from different IP camera via openCV I have an i7 12 core CPU and currently I can stream 4 HD IP cameras and display each camera in a 2 x 2 matrix overlay window but my issue is streaming these 4 camera is using 20% of my CPU unless I use sleep in each thread which then slows the display from there true frame rate. I am using timers to fire each thread that calls opencv to read each frame resize the image to the size of each matrix frame and passes each Mat buffer to Directx 11 overlay. If I set the cameras to stream at 25 FPS my timers to fire each thread event are set to 40 milliseconds which is 25 events every second but this is pulling my CPU down here is some of the code im using for my threads

```
 void mCam1(void * p)
        {
            COpenCVROIDlg* pThis = (COpenCVROIDlg*)p;
            v_Mat[pThis->m_MatrixView].copyTo(v_MatPre[pThis->m_MatrixView]);
            cv::Point pt;
            cv::Mat m_img, imgResized, m_matrix;
            if (!pThis->camera0.isOpened()) {
                // Send not connected to list control
            }else{
                pThis->camera0.read(m_img);
                if (m_img.empty()) {
                    //send no signal to list control
                }
                else {
                    cv::resize(m_img, imgResized, cv::Size(v_Cams[pThis->m_MatrixView][0].mPT.rc.right, v_Cams[pThis->m_MatrixView][0].mPT.rc.bottom), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR_EXACT);
                    Rect roi(v_Cams[pThis->m_MatrixView][0].mPT.pt.x, v_Cams[pThis->m_MatrixView][0].mPT.pt.y, imgResized.cols, imgResized.rows);
                    v_Mat[pThis->m_MatrixView].copyTo(m_matrix);
                    imgResized.copyTo(m_matrix(roi));
                    m_matrix.copyTo(v_Mat[pThis->m_MatrixView]);
                    cv::waitKey(1);
                }
            }
            cv::waitKey(84);// 12 frames per second
        }

      void CreateThreads(){
            m_hEventStream0 = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, 0);`
            ghOnvifThread[2] = CreateThread(
                NULL,              // default security
                0,                 // default stack size
                (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadCamera1,        // name of the thread function
                LPVOID(this),              // no thread parameters
                THREAD_TERMINATE | THREAD_SET_CONTEXT,                  // default startup flags
                &dwThreadID[2]);
 SetTimer(TM_CAMERA0, 10, NULL);
         }

        static LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE ThreadCamera1(LPVOID _pParam)
        {
            COpenCVROIDlg* pThis = (COpenCVROIDlg*)_pParam;
            HANDLE      hEvent;
            hEvent = m_hEventStream0;
            DWORD dwEventObject;
            __try
            {
                while (dwThreadID[2])
                {
                    dwEventObject = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
                    if (dwEventObject == (WAIT_OBJECT_0))
                    {
                        mCam1(pThis);
                    }
                }
            }
            __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
            {
            //  ExitThread(0x2222E000);
                return 0;
            }
            ExitThread(0x22220000);
            return 0;
        }
```

Can anyone show me an example or point me to a way where I can run multiple threads without causing excessive CPU over head. It seems with opencv I cant get each videocapture to tell me if theres a new image ready I have to keep probing it via the thread and read each frame that way.
Thanks

Comment: I have just run this code in release version of visual studio 2017 and my CPU is running around 7.6 to 9% streaming 4 HD cameras I do not have any other CPU to test performance Im wondering if this is excessive for this type of i7 CPU

Comment: Your thread's stopping condition looks wrong.  Thread handles don't just set themselves to NULL.  Your thread procedure has the wrong return type.  And your comment "no thread parameters" looks like a copy+paste bug.

Comment: Why is there any waiting in `mcam1`?  The thread procedure has a `WaitForSingleObject` call (which you probably should consider using with a waitable timer not an event, if you want to maintain consistent timing)

Comment: You are doing quite a lot of copying. Why don't you `resize` directly into `v_Mat[pThis->m_MatrixView](roi)`, instead of using two temporary `Mat`s? 
Btw: use some local variables for `pThis->m_MatrixView` and `v_Cams[pThis->m_MatrixView][0].mPT` to make the code shorter/easier to read.

Comment: Hi Ben Voigt  can you be more clear as to the wrong return type in the thread procedure? I changed static LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE to DWORD WINAPI  according to microsoft LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE can cause 64bit OS to crash I also changed WaitForSingleObject as you suggested.

Comment: I had one to may mat copys fixed this thanks for noticing that I have to resize each frame form each live stream which is resizing from 2048 * 1536 and depending on which Matrix position the images are resized to anything from 800 * 600  to 395 * 296 and 262 * 192 this is where the CPU is doing all the work any idea as how to make the resizing more efficient